# Upload multiple images using a many-to-many using Yii2

Tags: rest, yii2

How to make loading multiple images and making many-to-many relationships on a table of apartments?

I have a model Apartment:

```
public function getApartmentImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ApartmentImages::className(), ['apartment_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Images::className(), ['id' => 'image_id'])
        ->via('apartmentImages');
}
```

Model Images:

```
public function getApartmentImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ApartmentImages::className(), ['image_id' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getApartments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Apartment::className(), ['id' => 'apartment_id'])
        ->via('apartmentImages');
}
```

Model ApartmentImages

```
 public function getImage()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Images::className(), ['id' => 'image_id']);
}

public function getApartment()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Apartment::className(), ['id' => 'apartment_id']);
}
```

The apartment has a main image (layout) and many others.

I managed to make the layout load:

```
public function actionCreate()
{        
    $model = new Apartment();
    $model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '');
    $layout = new Images();
    $layout->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('layout');
    if ($layout->upload()) {
        $model->layout_id = $layout->id;
    }        
    if ($model->validate()) {
        if ($model->save()) {
            $response = Yii::$app->getResponse();
            $response->setStatusCode(201);
            $id = implode(',', array_values($model->getPrimaryKey(true)));
            $response->getHeaders()->set('Location', Url::toRoute(['view', 'id' => $id], true));
        } elseif (!$model->hasErrors()) {
            throw new ServerErrorHttpException('Failed to create the object for unknown reason.');
        }
    }
    return $model;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filled the array with all the sent pictures, and in the loop I upload to the site, and using

```
//INSERT INTO `apartment_images` (`apartment_id`, `image_id`) VALUES (...)
$model->link('images', $images[0]);
```

I create an entry in the link table.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Apartment();
    $model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '');
    $layout = new Images();
    $layout->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('layout');
    $layout->validate();
    if ($layout->upload()) {
        $model->layout_id = $layout->id;
    }
    $count = count(UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('images'));//Get the number of images
    $images = [new Images()];//First image required
    $images[0]->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('images[0]');
    if(!$images[0]->validate()) return $images[0]->errors;//Check errors
    if ($model->validate()){
        if ($model->save()) {
            if ($images[0]->upload()) {
                $model->link('images',$images[0]);//Binding many to many
            }
            for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {//Check the rest and repeat again
                $images[$i] = new Images();
                $images[$i]->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('images['.$i.']');
                if ($images[$i]->upload()) {
                    $model->link('images',$images[$i]);
                }
            }
            $response = Yii::$app->getResponse();
            $response->setStatusCode(201);
            $id = implode(',', array_values($model->getPrimaryKey(true)));
            $response->getHeaders()->set('Location', Url::toRoute(['view', 'id' => $id], true));
        } elseif (!$model->hasErrors()) {
            throw new ServerErrorHttpException('Failed to create the object for unknown reason.');
        }
    } 
    else return $model->errors;
    return $model;
}
```